# mysql --ignore-table - concise multiple

Tags: mysql

Is there a concise way to ignore multiple tables using `mysql --ignore-table`?

The documentation says that `--ignore-table` must be used for each table.

I have to ignore around 20 tables so the command is going to be huge

This must be run via the command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go the whitelist route instead of the blacklist route. From the man page:

```
mysqldump [options] [db_name [tbl_name ...]]
```

You still have to type everything out, but at least you don't have to continuously type the `--ignore-table` flag.

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunately the blacklist will always be a known quantity whereas the whitelist would be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Try using [MySQL Workbench](http://mysqlworkbench.org/) to build the command.  It'll give the option to specify which tables you want via checkboxes.

If you need to, you can copy and paste the command from the Export Progress tab.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stipulated that this needs to be done via command line

Comment: Not a problem, just copy the command it generated, and edit it as necessary.  Not sure of a quicker way to cherry pick which tables you want.